# Solution of the recurrence $T(n)=\sqrt{n}(T(\sqrt{n}))+n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Let $n=2^k$ and $T(2)=1$. Then, if we define $T(n)=\sqrt{n}(T(\sqrt{n}))+n$ for $n>2$, then what would be the exact solution of the recurrence?

The master theorem might not work here, and guessing a solution seems hard. In addition, I suspect $n=2^{2^k}$, for otherwise, we get irrational values. I think $T(n)=O(n\log n)$. But, is a better bound possible? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: You have unbalanced parentheses in definition of $T$.

Comment: @enedil thanks, edited now

Comment: What makes you believe that this uniquely defines a function $T$? What is the domain of $T$? Is it $\Bbb{R}_{>1}$?

Answer (score 1):

$$
T(e^{\ln n})=\sqrt n T(e^{\frac 12\ln n})+n
$$

or calling $T'(u) = T(e^u)$

$$
T'(\ln n) = \sqrt n T'(\frac 12\ln n) + n
$$

or

$$
T'(2^{\log_2(\ln n)}) = \sqrt n T'(2^{\log_2(\frac 12\ln n)})+n
$$

now calling $z = \log_2(\ln n)$ and $T''(z) = T'(2^z)$ we have

$$
T''(z) = e^{\frac 12 2^z}T''(z-1)+e^{2^z}
$$

This is a linear recurrence with solution

$$
T''(z) = C_1 e^{2^z-2}+ze^{2^z}
$$

and finally

$$
T(n) = C_1\frac{n}{e^2}+n\log_2(\ln n)
$$

Comment: So finally, $T(n)=n\ln(\ln n)$, right? Can this be proved by induction?

Comment: I meant $T(n)=O(n\ln \ln n)$